# Batch Files make Directory within Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

How would you create a directory inside of a directory in batch files? I've tried various times and I couldn't get it to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
md "dir 1"
cd "dir 1"
md "dir 2"
```

Or simply: `md "dir 1\dir 2"`.

Omit quotes if dir names have no spaces.

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to make "dir 2" **and** "dir 3" in "dir 1". _Not_ md "dir 1\dir 2\dir 3". Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried any testing on your own using the above information as a guideline?

Comment: @Nikpie7: That's simple enough. Since you know how to create "dir 2" in "dir 1" as I've shown above (via the shorter single command), can't you think of the equivalent command to create "dir 3" in "dir 1" too? Also, in future all these relevant details should be included in your question itself. If you forget to add something you can always [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/904871/edit) it in later.

Comment: My comment was directed to Nikpie7, the OP who's question and response shows very little effort put into testing. Your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mkdir -p /dir1/dir2
```

[From the mkdir man page:](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir)

> ```
>    -p, --parents
>       no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
> ```

`mkdir` with the `-p` flag allows creation of parent directories if they do not exist. If they do, the command continues to make the child directory without error.

Edit:
Just noticed this is for batch files, so probably Windows. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/905237/4820840:

> In Windows, mkdir creates directory trees by default.

mkdir a\b\c

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    setlocal enableextensions
        mkdir C:\test1\test2\test3
    endlocal
```

Answer (score -1):

in Linux:

```
mkdir -p /folder/subfolder/subsubfolder
```

In windows this one works:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905226/mkdir-p-linux-windows

Comment: Have you tried running this in Windows?

Comment: my fault, ill add the windows result.